# No database operations are done in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I created a database in phpmyadmin using xampp. When I make any operation on database tables(insert or delete row), loading panel appears then nothing happens and the operation does not executed in the table.I tried by gui command and by sql query.
Could anyone know what is the problem? knowing that The user of localhost has all privileges.

Comment: Check your error log files.

Comment: In error log file I found this note(server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name) what is that means??

Comment: It is repaired and I can do operations without any interference  !!!!